# iperf - first packet loss and acceptable jitter

Tags: voip, iperf, jitter

I'm using iperf to test the bandwidth on my network.  I have a few questions:
1. I'm running this command on the client: "iperft -c  -u -b 400m" and it successfully runs.  I'm running the command every few seconds.  I've found that if I run them too closely to each other, the first packet loses a good chunk of data (20% - 30%).  However, if I wait 2-3 seconds before consecutive commands, the first packet usually has no loss.  Is this an issue with iperf and my PC, as opposed to a problem with iperf and my network?
2. I'm getting jitter in the range of 0.079 ms and 0.536 ms.  Is this normal and/or acceptable?  What is an appropriate amount of jitter for a network to support VOIP, in your opinion?
Thanks, in advance, for your help!
- Charles

Comment: According one Cisco guy I spoke with a jitter less then ~40ms is all you should really need for good quality.